# Losing object reference when passing object function to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, object, requestanimationframe

I am wondering why these code variations are behaving the way they do.

First Setup:

```
var a = {

  val: 23,

  div: null,

  test: function(){

    this.div.innerHTML = this.div.innerHTML + ' ' + this.val;

  },

  run: function(){

    // why is "this" the window object here when called by requestAnimationFrame?

    requestAnimationFrame(this.run);

    this.test();

  },

  init: function(){

    this.div = document.getElementById('output');

    this.run();

  }

};

a.init();
```

This one I expected to work but fails as soon as `requestAnimationFrame` begins calling the `run` function as `this` refers to `Window` when called by `requestAnimationFrame`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/titansoftime/gmxourcq/

This one works:

```
var a = {

    val: 23,

    div: null,

    test: function(){

        this.div.innerHTML = this.div.innerHTML + ' ' + this.val;

    },

    run: function(){

        var self = this;

        requestAnimationFrame(function(){ self.run(); });

        this.test();

    },

    init: function(){

      this.div = document.getElementById('output');

      this.run();

    }

};

a.init();
```

Passing the `run` function via a closure solves the problem. Why would this work and not the prior example work? My actual code needs to run extremely efficiently and I'd rather not use a closure inside my run loop as I don't want to poke the GC. Perhaps this is not a big deal? (I'm mostly worried about mobile devices). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/titansoftime/Lqhcwoyu/

And finally the last case which works as expected:

```
var a = {

    val: 23,

    div: null,

    test: function(){

        this.div.innerHTML = this.div.innerHTML + ' ' + this.val;

    },

    run: function(){

        requestAnimationFrame(a.run);

        a.test();

    },

    init: function(){

      this.div = document.getElementById('output');

      this.run();

    }

};

a.init();
```

Again for performance (OCD) reasons I'd rather not reference this object via global if I can avoid it. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/titansoftime/5816fLxe/

Can someone please explain to me why the first example fails and also the best course to take regarding running this loop as memory/GC efficient as possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Or this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554136/setting-correct-this-value-in-requestanimationframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function reference that gets passed to `requestAnimationFrame` is executed in global context (where `this` refers to the `window` object, in the browser).

In order to execute the function reference passed to requestAnimationFrame in any other scope, you need to either [bind the function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to that scope:

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));
```

or pass in an anonymous wrapper function which essentially executes your function in it's original scope (which is what you've done here).

```
var self = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function(){ self.run(); });
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. Does one method have a benefit over the other performance wise?

Comment: the `bind` method essentially does the same thing as the anonymous function. A ridiculously simple test case says the Chrome's V8 prefers the anonymous ever so slightly (http://jsperf.com/raf-bind-vs-anonymous). I wouldn't worry about it either way, they're both very readable lines of code.

Comment: Once again, thank you =]